# Do M365 and Outlook desktop and mobile apps support deep linking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, deep-linking, microsoft365

I'm making a website where a user selects a date/time and clicks a button which redirects them to outlook.com with query params that create a calendar event with that date/time. I want to be able to open the Outlook desktop app and do the same thing, instead of the web app. I also want to do the same thing with the mobile apps for [Outlook](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-365-office/id541164041) and [M365](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596).

To open a desktop or mobile app via Javascript and create a calendar event like this, do those apps have to support deep links? How can I approach figuring out how to do this with Javascript?